# The connection "Connection" cannot be found. Verify that the connection manager has a connection with that name

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, ssis, odata, etl

I'm using an ODATA connection manager in SSIS to connect to a private Sharepoint Online, I manage to test the connection when I create the connection manager and to do a preview of my list when I'm in the designer. When I try to execute the package in VS I'm getting the following error:

> The connection "Connection" cannot be found. Verify that the connection manager has a connection with that name
>
> OData source failed validation and returned code 0xc020801A.

I already created a new package and I'm sure that there is no any other connection in logging tab, btw my other packages (which dont use an OData connection mgr. works perfectly)

My environment is configured as follows:

- VS Studio 2017 Community edition
- SQL Server Data Tools 15.1.61810.11040
- Sharepoint Online
- I installed also "SharePoint Server 2013 Client Components SDK" because with "SharePoint Online Client Components SDK" I could not even configure the connection manager in SSIS, since I was having the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime', Version=15.0.0.0

After installing the SDK 2013 I could configure correctly the connection manager.

Thank you in advance, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the OData connection can be found in the "connection managers" panel in the package, if it does, try to create a new solution and check if this error can be reproduced in it.

For the details on creating OData Source, please check this link: 
[Tutorial: Using the OData Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/tutorial-using-the-odata-source?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 0):

My sample test demo for your reference:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

look this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d8d524f0-d373-47d1-b239-424b26ac59a7/the-connection-quotconnectionquot-cannot-be-found-verify-that-the-connection-manager-has-a?forum=sqlintegrationservices

i have same problem

becuase languafe of IDE and SQL server is different (SQL Server - english, in IDE your national language)

simple solution is change in your dtsx name to "Connection"

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem but with the word "Conexión" in Spanish. I use Visual Studio 2019 in English, but I change the language to Spanish and everything worked.