# Odata error while extracting data from SSIS

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, odata

in SSIS 2015 i use OData component to get data from a URI when i press the button preview i got data back
but once i click start the project without even mapping it into a destination i got this error :

> Data Source [2]: The connection "connexion" was not found. Verify that
>   the connection manager contains a connection of this name. ODatasource
>   validation failed. Error Code: 0xC020801A

My tests :

- i have tried to deactivate the delay validation, still the same error.
- i have looked into logs but there is nothing called connexion there
- i have looked into the code source but there is nothing that called connexion on the code.
- i looked also on event hundler to see if there si anyting there but nothing

here is the screen shot to see the configuration of my componant :

[image: Odata configuration]

any one have any ideas how can i fix this, i'm stucking in a project and i don't have any other ideas

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to run a standalone package that uses a project connection manager which is not deployed.

There are many similar link mentioning the same problem:

- [SSIS Connection not found in package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874722/ssis-connection-not-found-in-package) *Check all answers*
- [The connection "Connection" cannot be found. Verify that the connection manager has a connection with that name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53926310/the-connection-connection-cannot-be-found-verify-that-the-connection-manager)
- [MSDN - The connection "Connection" cannot be found. Verify that the connection manager has a connection with that name](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d8d524f0-d373-47d1-b239-424b26ac59a7/the-connection-quotconnectionquot-cannot-be-found-verify-that-the-connection-manager-has-a?forum=sqlintegrationservices)